# String to 7-bit ASCII

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In C#, under the .NET Framework, on a WindowsForms Project, how could I convert a standard string (inputted via a text box) into the 7-bit ASCII version of that string (outputted into a separate text box)?

Here is some code that I have tried:

```
public static byte[] StringTo7bitAscii(string text)

{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if(((((bytes[i] * 0x0101010101010101UL) & 0x8040201008040201UL) % 0x1FF) & 1) == 0)
        {
            bytes[i] &= 0x7F;
        }
        else
        {
            bytes[i] |= 0x80;
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

After converting the return to a .ToString() so that it could go in my output textbox, all the textbox displayed was System.Byte[], regardless of input.

Comment: you should share some code that you have tried.

Comment: I will do so now.

Comment: You want something different than what you are saying - `byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);` already gives you exactly what you asking for... Can you please clarify what you want to see in the other textbox for example for "Bob 42"?

Comment: @AnuViswan how/why? ASCII is fixed width encoding of essentially [0-9a-Z] and UTF7 is variable width encoding for full Unicode range...

Comment: Ops, sorry, I read it wrong. Deleted it.

Comment: So for the input, just anything that you would be able to type on your keyboard. Let's say apple123. For the output I would like the 7-bit ASCII version of the text. By definition, that means taking the first 7 bits out of a series of bytes, and mapping them to their specific character defined by the ASCII code chart, then taking the next 7 bits and repeating. So if you entered apple123 you would get

Comment: Sorry! In the middle of my last comment, I found what I was looking for when tabbing back and forth between articles regarding the subject. I got 7-bit ASCII confused with 8-bit ASCII. I was thinking of 8-bit; 7-bit ASCII is just the global plaintext symbols you read and type with. *facepalm*. Thank you to everyone that contributed to my post, though! I appreciate it a lot!!

Comment: The bithack code does nothing useful, Encoding.ASCII already ensures that the byte value is [0..127].  Any character that cannot be converted is replaced by '?'.  The bug in this code, if it matters, is that it forgets to use Encoding.ASCII.GetString() to convert the byte[] back.

Comment: Like Hans said throw away your for loop and everything is fine. Also there is no 8-bit ASCII as it’s by definition 7-bit.